# How to evaluate $\int\frac{e^x+e^{2x}}{1+e^{2x}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to evaluate this
$$
\int\frac{e^x+e^{2x}}{1+e^{2x}}\:dx\,?
$$

This is my answer but I'm not sure if it is right:

$e^x+e^{2x}/2e^{2x}\cdot \ln(1+e^{2x})$

Comment: You want `e^{2x}` not `e^2x`. This is the difference between $e^{2x}$ and $e^2x$. (But even then, your answer is wrong.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**. By the change of variable
$$
u=e^x,\qquad du=e^xdx,
$$ one gets
$$
\int\frac{e^x+e^{2x}}{1+e^{2x}}\:dx=\int\frac{1+u}{1+u^2}\:du=\int\frac{du}{1+u^2}+\frac12\int\frac{2u}{1+u^2}\:du.
$$ Hope you can take it from here.

Comment: So, my answer is wrong

Comment: Yes you answer is wrong.

Comment: And can you integrate the final answer you wrote. Thanks

Comment: Observe that $$\int\frac{1}{1+u^2}\:du=\arctan u $$ and $$\frac12\int\frac{2u}{1+u^2}\:du=\frac12 \ln(1+u^2) $$ then put $u=e^x$.

Comment: What is the meaning of arcant u

Comment: @kaneki_kenNightcore $\arctan u=\tan^{-1}u$. Have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions

Comment: Thank you :-)  I have got it

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\dx}{\mathrm dx}\newcommand{\dv}{\mathrm dv}\newcommand{\du}{\mathrm du}$Another way is to split apart the integrand

$$I=\int\dx\frac {e^x+e^{2x}}{1+e^{2x}}=\underbrace{\int\dx\frac {e^x}{1+e^{2x}}}_{T_1}+\underbrace{\int\dx\frac {e^{2x}}{1+e^{2x}}}_{T_2}$$

Now, for each individual integral

$$T_1=\int\dv\frac 1{1+v^2}=\arctan e^x$$

and

$$T_2=\frac 12\int\du\frac 1u=\frac 12\log\left(1+e^{2x}\right)$$

Therefore

$$\int\dx\frac{e^x+e^{2x}}{1+e^{2x}}=\color{blue}{\arctan e^x+\tfrac 12\log\left(1+e^{2x}\right)+C}$$